# UFT-Connect to DB2 using JDBC instead of ODBC

Tags: jdbc, db2, odbc, hp-uft

In our UFT Automation scripts (VBScript) We normally connect to DB2 database to run queries using ODBC.

However due to some reason (probably windows patches/updates), on our workstations, ODBC is taking too long to connect (2-30min) compared to JDBC through squirrel (less than a sec). This happens for same parameters (workstation, network domain, id, passwords, SQL etc).

Is there any way to use JDBC to connect to DB2 database and use those functions in UFT/VBScript? Any pointers would be helpful. I'm using UFT 12.02 (not leanFT).

Comment: JDBC is Java based, and VBScript is not. It is highly unlikely that there are ready-made solutions for this.

Comment: It seems most likely that there is some overlooked difference in configuration between your JDBC and ODBC connections. *Possibly* you have very different JDBC driver version than ODBC driver. You *might* consider using an ODBC-to-JDBC Bridge (like [the one from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-jdbc-st/)) atop the quickly-connecting JDBC.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel: Yeah, just thinking about creating a JAR with some input and output parameters that serve my purpose. Unfortunately, I wanted to get a recordset object from database and not just a record value. Nevermind, will think more about it.

Comment: @TallTed : Yes, drivers are completely different (JDBC vs ODBC). Thanks for the link! I'll have a look to see if it helps.